# Timezone is not updating with the below script

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following code:

```
import os
os.system('tzutil /s "Alaskan Standard Time"')
```

however, it is not changing the timezone in windows unless I run it through a Command prompt.

Comment: Are you running it with administrative privileges?

Comment: im running as a python script.inside python script i merged the windows command